# Modbus TCP/IP device communication problems

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, modbus

I'm trying to communicate with a device using Modbus TCP/IP.  I'm using C# 4.0 .NET Sockets and have run into trouble getting responses back from the device.  It will have to be asynchronous communication due to the nature of the device/network.

Right now I can connect to the device.  When the `Connect` command executes, the device LED lights up that represents that there is an active connection.  Then I execute the `Send` command and the light turns off (meaning I've lost connection) and when I receive, I get nothing.  I've tried a bunch of different data packets but haven't been successful in any instance.  I am thinking, is it something with the `SocketType` when I initialize the Socket?  Could it be the port (currently using port 4) I'm trying to use?

Here is the Modbus TCP/IP document I've tried to use:
[Modbus Documentation](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf)

and here is my code:

```
sockPort = new Socket(IPAddress.Parse(_commInfo.IPAddress).AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);   
IPEndPoint m_localhost = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(addr.Address.ToString()), 4);    
sockPort.Bind(m_localhost);
sockPort.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_commInfo.IPAddress), 502));
byte[] rx = new byte[260];

byte[] data = { 0x03, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x04, 0x45, 0xf0 };

sockPort.Send(data);
var asf = sockPort.Receive(rx);
```

Comment: You don't need to bind local end of the socket. The issue is most probably with your interpretation of the application (modbus) protocol - endianness, etc. Use wireshark to check what is sent to/from the device.

Comment: Also, don't ignore return values from `send` and `receive` calls - they can be less then you expected.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov it looks like the device is responding, however I'm guessing my Port #4 isn't accepting connections.  Is there a way to use any available TCP port?

Comment: You should be all set for bi-directional communication on the socket once the `connect()` is complete. Don't `bind()` the local end - the kernel will select an *ephemeral* port for you.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov You were correct, it was my Modbus packet.  So now I'm able to send and receive from the device, however everytime I get a response, the supposed values of registers are always 0.  I'm stepping through the code too, so I should be giving it enough time to retrieve those values anyways.  Is this a hardware problem?

Comment: That's beyond my knowledge. Try looking for device-specific mailing list/groups/forums.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov would you like to submit an answer which would pretty much be a copy paste of your first three comments so I can mark it as so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most probably with your interpretation of the application (modbus) protocol - endianness, packet layout, etc. Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) or `tcpdump(1)` to figure out what is sent to and from the device. Some other points:

- You don't need to `bind(2)` the local end of the socket, kernel will select an *ephemeral* local port for you.
- You should be all set for bi-directional communication on the socket once the `connect(2)` is complete.
- Don't ignore return values from send and receive calls - they can be less then you expected.

As for workings of the device itself it's probably best to look for manufacturer documentation
 and search for device-specific mailing lists, user groups, and forums.

Hope this helps.